# Cant install hostapd

Tags: networking, pi-3b+

So I removed hostapd with

```
sudo remove hostapd
```

but the folder

```
/etc/hostapd
```

still exist but even when I use

```
sudo apt install hostapd
```

it won’t bring back

```
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

or the other files in

```
/etc/hostapd
```

And therefore I can’t edit the file or activate hostapd

Edit:
Output from sudo rm /etc/hostapd:

rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/hostapd’: Is
a directory

Comment: Unless you provide some details, we cannot help you. If it can't install, there is an error-message saying why it won't install. What is that error message? Why can't the file be removed? What error message do you get there?

Comment: Welcome.  As per the previous comment, you'll need to provide the output from `sudo rm /etc/whatever-file-you-mean`.

Comment: please read the comment from @goldilocks again ... you did not follow the request

Comment: I’ve added the error output @goldilocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original version of your post referred to "the *file* in /etc", which is why I said to try `sudo rm /etc/whatever-file-you-mean`.  To remove a directory with `rm`, you need to use `-r` or `-d`, see `man rm`.  You really should be at least looking at the [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) of commands that are new to you when you first use them. This could save you the time and hassle of having to ask for help with relatively simple things.

Anyway, to remove a directory you can also use `rmdir` -- but it only works on empty directories.  To make an educated guess, probably the reason the directory was not removed was because it contains configuration files that have been changed since they were installed; the point of that is so you do not loose config files you may want to use again. Generally re-installing will respect this, I think, but perhaps not in all cases (actually it sounds like that is what happened).

So the solution here is (if hostapd is still installed, `sudo apt remove hostapd` first):

```
sudo rm -r /etc/hostapd
```

From `man rm`:

> `-r, -R, --recursive`
>
> ```
>          remove directories and their contents recursively
> ```

This means you could delete the entire root filesystem with `rm -r /`, so be careul with it.